# Select the rows with maximum non na columns from a continuous set of of n rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with time index, and a few columns with numerical values, but also containing missing values on certain occasions.
For eg:

```
timeindex   ColA    ColB    ColC
00:02:00      454    436    4334
00:04:00             653
00:06:00      3423   4354 
00:08:00      3432
00:10:00      2343
00:12:00     32432          23423
```

I would like to create a subset of the dataframe such that for every consecutive group of 3 rows, it picks the row that has the lowest number of missing values.
So for the above df, the subsetdf would look like:

```
timeindex   ColA    ColB    ColC
00:02:00      454    436    4334
00:12:00     32432          23423
```

Can you advise how i can achieve this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.filter` to select the columns, check for empty strings, `sum` on axis 1 and then finally `groupby.idxmax`

```
idx = (df.assign(count=df.filter(like="Col").notnull().sum(1))
         .groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3)["count"].idxmax())

print (df.loc[idx])

  timeindex   ColA ColB   ColC
0  00:02:00    454  436   4334
5  00:12:00  32432       23423
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot perform __floordiv__ with this index type: Index

Comment: Then use `np.arange(len(df))//3` instead of `df.index//3`.

Comment: For some reason the output is not picking rows with the lowest null value columns...
it is simply picking the 3rd row of each 3 row groups

Comment: The empty value is nan

Comment: Then why would you provide a sample df with empty values as above? It would be so much simplier if its just nan.

Comment: Apologies in that case, it was numerical column all along, nan was implied i thought.
please advise

Answer (score -1):

```
# split the dataframe into groups of 3
df_dict = {n: df.iloc[n:n+3, :] 
           for n in range(0, len(df), 3)}

# find indexes of the minimum number of None for each group
mask = []
for g in df_dict.values():
    mask.append((g.isnull().sum(axis=1)).idxmin())

# keep only those rows
df.iloc[mask]
```

if you meant to empty and not None:

Replace this row:

```
mask.append((g.isnull().sum(axis=1)).idxmin())
```

By this row:

```
mask.append((g.eq('').sum(axis=1)).idxmin())
```